# How to make change (to get coins from a banknote) in Italy?

Tags: money, italy, tips-and-tricks, local-customs, verona

So I arrived with my rental in Verona and it turns out that you need coins to pay for parking. What is the best way to exchange bills to coins? At 1€ an hour 14 hours a day I need a bunch - not just what you get from buying coffee with 10€ bills.

Comment: Does your local bank have a branch nearby?

Comment: not likely - SEB of Sweden. :-)

Comment: You wont get coin changer easily in Italy. The best solution is the one suggested by **Alessandro** (although the owner will expect you to also buy something) or the one suggested by **ratchet freak**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Enter a bar or supermarket and ask if they can change your 10€ bill into 1€ / 2€ coins for the parking. Repeat again in some other place. Probably they will stare badly at you. You're not obliged to consume or buy anything. Be warned that some cashiers may refuse your request.

This is a common behaviour even for italians.

[This site](http://www.turismoverona.eu/nqcontent.cfm?a_id=35617&tt=turismo) reports that parking meter accept "bancomat" (debit card). An alternative would be to buy a pre-paid *Verona Park* coupon.

Comment: Yes bar/supermarket employees are likely to give you a bad stare and look like they're upset at you asking to change money. Never understood why. Disregard their attitude, smile, thank them and keep on moving. :)

Comment: Coins are precious to give proper change back to customers. If you run out of coins it can be *very* annoying... people in queue starting to get grumpy, you have to open a coin roll yourself (some can be quite hard), ask other cashiers to exchange, go yourself to the nearest place to get the bill exchanged... many unfortunate coincidences I experimented myself when working in a shop =)

Comment: @JoErNanO: "Never understood why." - They're not there as a free-of-charge money exchange service. They're not paid for it, and possibly, they are even told by their employer not to do it, so it's up to them to either deal with dissatisfied strangers whose requests they have to decline, or with a dissatisfied boss whose orders they violate. I don't find it particularly hard to understand that they're not happy about such requests then.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper None of those are reasons to give one a bad stare. Rather, those can be reasons to politely decline. Try walking in a bar in Italy and asking for change. The way you'll be treated is likely to make you feel like you asked for a kidney transplant. *That's* something I never understood.

Comment: Will try the Verona Park thing tomorrow now that I am out of coins....

Comment: @JoErNanO I'd imagine it could be because you're asking for service without even buying anything. Kinda like walking into a restaurant in the US just to ask if you can use their bathroom.

Answer (score 28):

Look for unmanned automatic laundry places. Since the washers/dryers there are usually coin-operated, you'll find  a coin dispensing machine to convert your notes into shrapnel. You're likely to also find similar machines at self-service car-washes, or in any other business providing coin-operated services. They usually look something like this:

[image: coin dispensing machine]

<sup>*Cassa per lavanderia a gettoni self service, LAVATU, Fair use*</sup>

Comment: The same thing can be done at almast any automatic carwash.

Comment: Good suggestion. I went by one earlier today - will try it later!

Comment: Tried this - didn't work. One place also accepted bills so no coins there. And the other place could produce play money from bills but no real money.

Answer (score 11):

Walk into a bank with €25 and ask for a coin roll of 1 Euro coins.

You will get a yellow roll with 25 of them in exchange. You can also get a purple roll of 2 Euro coins for €50.

Comment: I've actually never done this in Italy, hence why I did not post it as an answer. I don't know if you have to be a customer of the bank or not. Might give it a try one day.

Comment: I tried once. They may or may not exchange the money if you're not client of the bank. If you are a foreigner they will probably do.

Comment: Banks elsewhere charge for this, even their own clients. Is it generally free in Italy?

Comment: @Relaxed no bank charges for this service. Rather, they *claim* to charge an inordinate fee as a form of refusal (since no reasonable person would pay, for instance, $5 for the privilege of changing $20 into coins). Also, banks often threaten to 'charge you next time' in the same way that traffic cops claim they are going to fine you next time. In neither case is a record of your identity kept in order to determine if you are on your second time or not. In both cases the intention is to elicit a show of gratitude and repentance.

Comment: @jwg What are you talking about? How do you pretend to know that no bank charges for this service? My bank does for example. The only way to get coins from them is with your debit card and the machine charges a little more than the amount you get in coins (fee is €0.25 for a €25 euro roll or something like that). In fact, if you ask a human being for cash in any shape or form, they tell you they have none and direct you to one of the machines in the branch. E.g. if you don't have a debit card and you want money from an account, they prepare a disposable debit card for the ATM to swallow.

Comment: @Relaxed time to change banks.

Answer (score 4):

You can often find coin dispensing machine in Post Offices

Comment: Flagged up in LQP queue.  Can you add something helpful to the OP here? For example where are the post offices in Verona? How would the OP recognize one? Is there an all night post office? Anything that can elevate the quality of this answer will be great, thanks.

Comment: You won't find coin dispensers in Italy's post offices.